# how to customize my Google form - something is wrong

Tags: php, google-forms

I want to customize my google form, and I almost got it right. It's just one field that is not working. It's the first field in this page: http://hagefornyelse.no/gratis-befaring/ 
The entries in the first field is not registrated. But all other fields is working properly. What have I done wrong?

Here is the code I have made that regards the first field in the http://hagefornyelse.no/gratis-befaring page:

```
<div class="ss-form-container">
<div class="ss-form"><form id="ss-form" action="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=dGFvbzZqVWtOT3RBemdXZzVEbWREYWc6MQ&amp;ifq" method="POST">
<div class="errorbox-good">
<div class="ss-item ss-text">
<div class="ss-form-entry"><label class="ss-q-title" for="entry_0">Hva ønsker du hjelp til?
</label><input id="entry_0" class="ss-q-short" name="entry.0.single" type="text" value="" />

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the code from the Google form.

```
<div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" role="listitem">
<div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-text»>
<div class="ss-form-entry">
<label class="ss-q-item-label" for="entry_2444089»>
<div class="ss-q-title">Hva ønsker du hjelp til? 
</div> 
<div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr»>
</div>
</label> 

<input type="text" name="entry.2444089" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_2444089" dir="auto" aria-label="Hva ønsker du hjelp til? " title="»> 
<div class="error-message" id="1918730340_errorMessage»>
</div> 

<div class="required-message">Dette er et obligatorisk spørsmål
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

What have I done wrong in the first field "Hva ønsker du hjelp til?" ?

Comment: What browser are you testing it in? I tested this in Chrome, and the entry field was properly submitted (via post) to the server. Are you sure you are interpreting it correctly on the server side? (Form data here: entry.2444089=abcdefg)

Comment: thanks @Mark But march the second it was fixed by a programmer :) I couldn't wait that long :)